Forward search next occurance in parallel column
I must find the next occurance of one column in a parallel column. The search should only be performed forward/downward. An example is this:
library(tidyverse)

d <- tribble(~from, ~to, ~type, ~want,
         "a", "b", 9, 8,
         "b", "c", 8, 0,
         "a", "x", 6, 7,
         "c", "d", 0, 3,
         "c", "d", 5, 3,
         "x", "y", 7, NA,
         "d", "e", 3, 4,
         "e", "f", 4, 5, 
         "e", "f", 2, 5,
         "e", "f", 8, 5,
         "f", "g", 5, NA)

The rule is as follows: find the value of column type according to column to using the lookup column from. For example, to = "b" in row 1, the next occurance of value b in column from is 8, which gives the value for column want (want is the desired result and unknown initially), etc. The lead is not always 1, there can be rows between. Is there a simple way to do this?
Second example:
d2 <- tribble(~from, ~to, ~type,
          "a", "b", 0,
          "b", "a", 1,
          "a", "c", 2)


This question has been closed due to it being unclear. Notice that the next occurrence in column from is in row 2 and that has the value type = 8.. You should have stated that. Not claiming that the next value of b is 8. That is not clear

You could use non-equi join:
rowid_to_column(d) %>%
  left_join(y = {.}, join_by(to == from,rowid < rowid), multiple = 'first') %>%
  select(from, to, type=type.x, want = type.y)

# A tibble: 11 × 4
   from  to     type  want
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a     b         9     8
 2 b     c         8     0
 3 a     x         6     7
 4 c     d         0     3
 5 c     d         5     3
 6 x     y         7    NA
 7 d     e         3     4
 8 e     f         4     5
 9 e     f         2     5
10 e     f         8     5
11 f     g         5    NA


rowid_to_column(d2) %>%
  left_join(y = {.}, join_by(to == from,rowid < rowid), multiple = 'first') %>%
  select(from, to, type=type.x, want = type.y)

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  from  to     type  want
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a     b         0     1
2 b     a         1     2
3 a     c         2    NA


If you want speed/efficiency, use data.table:
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[, n := .I][d, .(from, to = i.to, type = i.type, want = type), 
                  on = .(from == to, n > n), mult = 'first']

      from     to  type  want
    <char> <char> <num> <num>
 1:      a      b     9     8
 2:      b      c     8     0
 3:      a      x     6     7
 4:      c      d     0     3
 5:      c      d     5     3
 6:      x      y     7    NA
 7:      d      e     3     4
 8:      e      f     4     5
 9:      e      f     2     5
10:      e      f     8     5
11:      f      g     5    NA


Base R solution. But not suitable for bigger data.frame since it is a O(n^2) algorithm.
foo <- function(df) {
 pos_below <- \(i) with(df, type[Position(\(x) x == to[i], from[-seq_len(i)]) + i])
 df$want <- sapply(seq(nrow(df)), pos_below)
 df
}


foo(d)
#    from  to     type  want
#    <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#  1 a     b         9     8
#  2 b     c         8     0
#  3 a     x         6     7
#  4 c     d         0     3
#  5 c     d         5     3
#  6 x     y         7    NA
#  7 d     e         3     4
#  8 e     f         4     5
#  9 e     f         2     5
# 10 e     f         8     5
# 11 f     g         5    NA

foo(d2)
#   from  to     type  want
#   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a     b         0     1
# 2 b     a         1     2
# 3 a     c         2    NA


This is technically not correct. eg if to of row 8 was b then the forward search would be NA not 8. you cannot use match.

Thanks, s_baldur, but it sometimes flips: for d2 (above) it gives 1,0,NA instead of 1,2,NA

I had misunderstood Onaymbu's comment. Should be fixed now @r.user.05apr
